# Home-brew automatic tiered storage solutions with Linux? (Memory -> SSD -> HDD -> remote storage)

Tags: linux, unix, ssd, archive, storage

Related to [this question about using an SSD for system and HDD for data](https://serverfault.com/questions/26453/ssd-for-system-and-hdd-for-data-for-desktop-environnement), except I would like my system to do this automatically...

Is it possible to have several layers of storage and push items automatically between them, using preferably free, open-source software?

I know of hugely expensive enterprise-class solutions like the EMC SAN->[EMC Centera](http://www.emc.com/products/family/emc-centera-family.htm) automatic archiving, but I was wondering if this sort of staged storage is possible to do automatically.

It would be nice to be able to have several layers in this :  Memory->SSD->HDD->slower HDD or tape or some other archive solution.

*Are there any filesystems which can do this automatically?* (ZFS, Btrfs, HAMMER?)

Any **Unix**-variants are fine, as I'm interested in how this works and whether it's likely to be portable to Linux or other flavours (BSD etc).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, ZFS uses a storage layering called [Hybrid Storage Pool (HSP)](https://blogs.oracle.com/ahl/entry/fishworks_launch):

1. Layer: memory
2. Layer: SSD-based read-caches (L2ARC) and write-caches (separate intent log aka slog).
3. Layer: (cheap) harddisks

With HSP its easy to automatically benefit from the advantages of SSDs compared to a harddisk-only solution. A system using HSP can be both faster and cheaper than the latter. See [this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/brendan/entry/slog_screenshots) for some nice examples and more details.

I think there are plans regarding [hierarchical storage management (HSM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_storage_management) for ZFS (see for example the [Automatic Data Migration (ADM)](http://opensolaris.org/os/project/adm/) OpenSolaris project) but I don't know its current status.

Comment: This is just what I was thinking of, thanks!
(Now to help on the Linux port... ;)

Comment: I would not call this tiering but caching. In the sense that  caching means keeping a copy of frequently used blocks, tiering *moving* the data to slower/faster storage. I would not call the intent log in ZFS a real write cache if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the LVM based "lvmts" (LVM Tiered Storage) solution this guy is cooking up:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1140640#p1140640

Pretty cool.

Comment: +1 This looks very interesting -- I shall be keeping an eye on it!

Answer (score 5):

TIER seems to answer your needs
It is a linux kernel module that can create a tiered storage. It seems to learn by itself the pattern and optimize the placement into the storage

http://www.lessfs.com/wordpress/?p=776

Comment: Just saw the question is _old_ ... Sorry ^^'

Comment: Revitalising old questions is better than having then rotting with old and out-of-date information on them!

Comment: I'm worried that this guy wants to reduce redundancy for the sake of extra capacity (especially when SSDs are comparatively small and unreliable).

Comment: Also worried that he suggests raid as the solution, when experimental software needs backups most.

Comment: Here's a bit of more positive feedback though: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.ceph.devel/8316

Answer (score 1):

[SAM-QFS](http://www.opensolaris.org/os/project/samqfs/) is Sun's existing product and was open-sourced last year. It's CDDL, so you could only directly port it to *BSD.

Answer (score 1):

*Answering my own question with something I just found:*

I was just updating the kernel and looking at the new stuff that has been added, and 

[**there is now a 'CACHEFILES' option**](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/caching/cachefiles.txt) which allows for caching (usually remote) filesystems to a local filesystem.  I guess I could use this to cache a slower storage mechanism (HDD) to a faster one (SSD), at least for one level of hierarchy.

Comment: Did you try this solution? How does it perform?

Comment: Nevermind - I found out myself that CacheFS for now only supports NFS and AFS.

Comment: Using network filesystems for this isn't a bad idea, they tend to mature much faster than kernel patchsets. I wonder if Ceph or DRBD have useful modes for tiered storage.

Answer (score 1):

Some relevant links.  YMMV.

http://code.google.com/p/fscops/ -- "Online Hierarchical Storage Manager (OHSM) is the first attempt towards an enterprise level open source data storage manager which automatically moves data between high-cost and low-cost storage media.".

http://www.tack.ch/unix/dmapi/ -- XFS + DMAPI under Linux

http://jfs.sourceforge.net/ -- JFS + DMAPI under Linux

Comment: The OHSM project looks like an interesting one to follow.  Only ext2 and the 2.6.30 kernel is supported for now, but I expect if it works out well then this will gain more filesystems.

Comment: That project looks abandoned, most recent activity was in 2009.

Answer (score 1):

RAID controllers offer some of these features.

"Leverages SSDs in front of HDD volumes to create high-capacity, high-performance controller cache pools"

http://www.lsi.com/channel/products/storagesw/Pages/MegaRAIDCacheCadeSoftware2-0.aspx

Answer (score 0):

LVM2 snapshots come to mind... but you can't really do more than a single snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

btier (7 years old)

autofs (recent, file based)