# Intelligent Volume Management

Tags: raid, lvm

I'm looking for a software solution that could present a single disk volume to me that's backed by some sort of intelligent disk manager.

In my ideal use case I'd be able to create the volume from several classes of storage (let's say we're on AWS so EBS and S3) and provide some logic for deciding when data should be moved from one underlying storage volume to the other.

E.g "*data < 2 days old stays on the EBS volume, older data gets moved off to S3*"

I know I can create a LVM logical volume that's backend by an S3 physical volume and a EBS physical volume, but could I tell it which underlying PV to use for what data?

[EDIT] - Something I thought of would be if I could control where new extents are created. It may be possible/sane to move older extents to a certain disk within an LV and then start allocating newer ones onto another disk. LVM does not appear to offer controls beyond moving all extents from one disk to another (for the purposes of replacing a disk from a cluster) that I can see.

Comment: Ideally the application consuming this data would be oblivious to the underlying storage mechanism so moving data from one path to another is something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: looks like this concept is known as "tiering"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Home-brew automatic tiered storage solutions with Linux? (Memory -> SSD -> HDD -> remote storage)](http://serverfault.com/questions/44026/home-brew-automatic-tiered-storage-solutions-with-linux-memory-ssd-hdd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Various products offer storage tiering for various types of storage in the same platform, everything from FAST VP on EMC VNX SAN to tiering in systems like ZFS and Storage Spaces.

If you're looking for something to bridge storage at multiple sites, or mix cloud and local/LAN storage, then it sounds like you might be served by a [cloud storage gateway.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_storage_gateway)

Something like [Riverbed SteelStore](http://www.riverbed.com/products/cloud-storage/#How_It_Works) can be used to connect to multiple different local and remote/cloud storage platforms in a unified, seamless manner.  This is just one example, there are similar products out there, but product recommendations are outside the scope of this site.